# Kitten ate some coffee grounds

Tags: cats, health, eating, treats

Kitten jumped into trash after I dumped my coffee grounds and then licked some off his paws. He’s 3 months old. Should I be worried?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! In general: if your cat starts to act in other ways than it used to, you should call or see a vet. Do not wait for guesses of strangers in the internet if the health of your pet is at risk!